# asp.net site demo over webex, weird issues seen

Tags: asp.net, exception, webex

Our customer experienced multiple errors on a demonstration to a customer of theirs.

The site is asp.net 3.5 based and has been running pretty well lately. They said 2 hours later site was ok again... (needless to say they are not happy)

The traces in the health log look very weird, it appeared to be as if incomplete pages were returning to the server for processing..

A fair of of the errors were errors generated by scriptresource.axd with bits of the page source showing up as part of the url... very very odd. I'd never seen this before...

I was talking to their lead tester who then told me this only happened during a webex (cisco sharing product) demo and was fine after...

Is it possible the webex session could have impacted the site http stream between client and server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known IE8 issue. I bet you will see Trident/4.0 for all "broken" requests in the user agent field. (Google for "IE8 4K bug")

You can either run a different browser or appply the latest IE8 patch (this issue has already been fixed)

Comment: Ah... my health log unfortunately only picks up the server exceptions but I may write a little capture log and ask him to test it to capture the full request object.

It was indeed IE8!

Comment: I had a read of that IE8 4K bug, wow odd!
The funny thing is 3 symptoms mentioned here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/bugs-in-the-ie8-lookahead-downloader.aspx mirror some of what is in the log. Odd requests for non existent resources but the user didn't see any script issues...

Comment: The user won't see the error because there will be a parser restart and the script will load fine. But you WILL see errors (from the 1st broken request) on the server end.

Comment: yip, thats exactly what appears to have occurred. Thanks again Dmitry